# IndexedDB put/add failing silently in Chrome (for all websites)

Tags: google-chrome, indexeddb

After some successful development using IndexedDB on Chrome, all write operations just stopped working without giving any error.
Everything is fine with Safari.

Here is a straightforward sample not working:

```
var db = null;
var req = indexedDB.open("TestDb", 1);

req.onsuccess = function(event) {
    db = event.target.result;
    db.onerror = function(event) {
      error('Error: ', event.target.errorCode);
    };

    var os = db.transaction(['users'], "readwrite").objectStore('users');
    req = os.put({id: 2, name: 'Benoît'});

    req.onsuccess = function (event) {
        console.log('Put success', event.target.result);

        var os = db.transaction(['users'], "readwrite").objectStore('users');
        var req = os.get(2);
        req.onsuccess = function(event) {
            console.log('Get success', event.target.result);
        }

    };
    req.onerror = function (event) {
        console.log('error', event);
    };
};

req.onupgradeneeded = function(ev) {
    console.log('db upgradeneeded', ev);
    var db = ev.target.result, objectStore;

    if (ev.oldVersion < 1) {
        objectStore = db.createObjectStore('users', {keyPath: "id"});
        objectStore.createIndex("name", "name", {unique: false});
    }
};
```

Resulting in console log:

> Put success 2
>
> Get success undefined

Comment: For additional debugging, add oncomplete and onabort handlers to the transaction:

`var tx = db.transaction(['users'], "readwrite"), os = tx.objectStore('users');
tx.oncomplete = function() { console.log('completed'); };
tx.onabort = function() { console.log('aborted'); };`

Comment: @theredled does the error occur when you use only one transaction?

Comment: Thanks guys, but I only had a disk space problem. Should throw an error but anyway, it's ok!

Comment: Yep - that'd cause the transaction to abort, but no particular request would have an error. That's why it's a good idea to watch for abort events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there was not enough space on disk.

As said by @Joshua Bell, the query successes but the transaction aborts, so you need to watch `transaction.onabort` to raise an error message.

Comment: This ended a half-hour session of confused swearing. Not watching `onabort` got me. Thank you!